# LibGDX Flip ModelInstance

Tags: java, animation, libgdx

with 2D sprites I could easily flip/mirror sprite with

```
batch.draw(reg.getTexture(), position.x, position.y, origin.x, origin.y, dimension.x, dimension.y, scale.x, scale.y,
            rotation, reg.getRegionX(), reg.getRegionY(), reg.getRegionWidth(), reg.getRegionHeight(),
            **/*FLIP HERE*/**,
                false);
```

I've 2D Model walking object with G3DB format created by 3D modelling, stored in ModelInstance, could you show me how to flip it? or Should I create multiple object for each walking direction (Right/Left)

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to flip modelInstance just use :

```
modelInstance.transform.scale(x, y, z);
```

and don't forget to disable back face culling like this.

```
DefaultShader.defaultCullFace = 0;
```

thanks and credit to [Xoppa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2512687/xoppa)